# Change file type association in Fedora/KDE

Tags: fedora, kde

Can anybody explain how to change file extension associations with applications to open them with in Fedora/KDE ?  E.g. my PDFs open with Okular and I would like to change the default to Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can set under *System Settings (Workspace Appearance and Behaviour) -> Default Applications*, such as the terminal and browser app to use.

With regard to things opened from the KDE file manager, Dolphin, I believe those are contolled from *System Settings (Common Appearance and Behaviour) -> File Associations*.  While I do use fedora+kde, I don't actually use dolphin, so I can't say for sure which is the right one WRT, eg, pdfs, but *application->pdf* looks promising (there's a search there too).

You will probably also be interested in [this dolphin feature](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management/en#Change_a_File_Association_on-the-fly).

Comment: Actually, while I do have Dolphin installed, I prefer using Thunar.  Do you know if it is possible to set it at a global and not just FS browser level so that it works regardless from which FS browser you open it from?

Comment: @foampile By incorporating it into the "Systems Settings", KDE is maybe making the attempt, but doing that at the DE level is pointless: by that logic all file browsers would then have to implement umpteen DE methodologies.  The "freedesktop.org" group who have to a significant degree instituted some pan-linux or posix standards of this sort would seem the most appropriate organization to try such a thing.  I think the great majority of users use one file browser or another and won't consider setting this a big hassle anyway ;)

Comment: in fact, when i followed your instructions, Adobe is indeed on top and Okular is 2nd but Thunar still opens it with Okular

Comment: @foampile  Right, because nothing other than a KDE specific app is going to implement and check for a KDE specific configuration method.  I suppose the KDE people could create something which automagicly hacked the configuration of whatever (popular) installed detected filebrowsers, but that would be quite the mess.  So short of a common standard, there you are.